# How to skip agent phase in TFS release definition

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using TFS 2017 update 2 on premise for CI and CD. In my release definition I have multiple "agent phase". Is there any possibility to skip the entire "agent phase" based on some conditions?

Comment: @kayess It's perfectly clear if you're familiar with the release capabilities in TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that capability doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

An **agent phase** is a way of defining a sequence of tasks that will run on one or more agents. At run time, one or more jobs are created to be run on agents that match the demands specified in the phase properties.

Unlike the build task, you could not simply disable/skip the task by right click it and select "*disable selected task(s)*". You need  configure the **Run this phase** properties for an agent phase to run or not when specific [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions) are met.

[image]

For "custom" you need to enter an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions) that evaluates to **true** or **false** and controls when this phase should run. This is for the single agent phase. It's not able to skip the entire "agent phase"  on some conditions.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your comment.But we are using TFS on premise. "Run this phase" is not available in TFS 2017 update2 on permise. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @user3744418 As Daniel said that it is not supported in TFS 2017 update2.